# How to return response to .aspx page from Handler in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, handler

I've just start working with handlers in asp.net and I've got one question.
I have PostRequestPage.aspx page with such structure:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" Text="Enter request" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <span id="error"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Send" />
```

And I send my POST to handler using ajax post like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
                var txtEmail = '<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "HandlerWithPOST.ashx",
                    data: $('#' + txtEmail).val(),                       
                    dataType:"json",                   
                });
            });
        })
```

In handler I get my POST data:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
                    {
 String requestFromPost = reader.ReadToEnd();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(requestFromPost);
}
```

Then I process my data and get the response I want to return to PostRequestPage.aspx page :

```
String jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { result = results });
```

The question is how can I show my jsonResult in label,for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend your ajax method like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "HandlerWithPOST.ashx",
    data: $('#' + txtEmail).val(),                       
    dataType:"json",                   
    success: function (data) {
        // do some magic with your json data, like populating your label
    }   
});
```

Take a look at the jQuery.ajax() api: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @ cherry3
Sorry for long reply.
I resolve the problem by removing dataType:"json"

Answer (score 0):

for write data to response try

```
context.Response.Write(jsonResult)
```

also before write set

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Comment: Thanks,you answer is absolutelly rigth,but it will not work for me,as I send POST from another page and 
context.Response.Write(jsonResult)
will not show anything on it

Comment: it's must place inside handler

Comment: on client handle success function as answer @cherry3

Answer (score 0):

you can write the response in context and it will be avilable in success handler for ajax hit as follows :

```
context.Response.Write(jsonResult)

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "HandlerWithPOST.ashx",
data: $('#' + txtEmail).val(),                       
dataType:"json",                   
success: function (data) {
    console.log("your data from handler is")
```

`console.log(data ? data.d : null)`
    }
});

Thanks,
Abhishek S.